# Entity Framework Code First Design

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm doing the design for a Councillors Directory using Entity Framework 6 and am after some guidance on how to structure my entities. Been a while since I've done anything from scratch like this, any help would be much appreciated. I'm more used to doing this database first, rather than code first and it's taking awhile to switch how I'm thinking about things.

I have two entities:

```
public class Councillor
{
    [Key]
    public int CouncillorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Committee> Committees { get; set; }
}

public class Committee
{
    [Key]
    public int CommitteeId { get; set; }
    public string CommitteeName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Councillor> Councillors { get; set; }
}
```

There is a **many to many** relationship in that a Councillor can sit on many Committees and a Committee has many Councillors.

To add to this a Committee has Councillors that act as Chairmen, Vice-Chairman or just Members. The List handles the later, but I'm looking for suggestion (best practice) on setting the other positions.

I'm currently thinking of going with:

```
public class Committee
{
    [Key]
    public int CommitteeId { get; set; }
    public string CommitteeName { get; set; }
    public int ChairmanId { get; set; } // link to councillor entity
    public int ViceChairId { get; set; } // link to councillor entity
    public ICollection<Councillor> Councillors { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions or problems with this approach? In database first I'd likely just have a link table for members of committees with CouncillorId, CommitteeId and Position. But can't get my head around how to translate that to code first.

Comment: Mike, are you using Code First to New Database or Code First to Existing Database?

Comment: Code First to a new database, based on old database that has a number of issues.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/ "Avoid many-to-many mappings in ORMs"

Comment: Interesting read, basically stop pretending the junction / link table doesn't exist and model it, which makes it easy to work on later. Looks a solid way of doing things and more like db first.

Comment: Jimmy Bogard (Creator of AutoMapper) also had a really good presentations about ORMS in general: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5688-orms-you-re-doing-it-wrong He is opinionated, and you don't have to agree with it all, but the questions he raises provide a good understanding of how to view and use ORMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to add a junction table to join your councillors to committees.  I'd keep the chairman and vice chairman properties on the committee object.

```
public class Councillor
{
    [Key]
    public int CouncillorId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Junction Table Navigation Property
    [ForeignKey("CouncillorId")]
    public virtual ICollection<CouncillorCommittee> CouncilorCommittees { get; set; }
}

public class Committee
{
    [Key]
    public int CommitteeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ChairmanId { get; set; }

    public int ViceChairmanId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChairmanId")]
    public virtual Councillor Chairman { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ViceChairmanId")]
    public virtual Councillor ViceChairman { get; set; }

    // Junction Table Navigation Property
    [ForeignKey("CommitteeId")]
    public virtual ICollection<CouncillorCommittee> CouncilorCommittees { get; set; }
}

// Represents the joining table
public class CouncillorCommittee
{
    [Key]
    public int CouncillorCommitteeId { get; set; }

    public int CouncillorId { get; set; }

    public int CommitteeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CouncillorId")]
    public virtual Councillor Councillor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CommitteeId")]
    public virtual Committee Committee { get; set; }
}
```

Within your code, you would then have something like this to get a list of committees and the councillors:

```
var committees =  from c
                  in Committees
                  select new
                  {
                      CommitteeName = c.Name,
                      Chairman = c.Chairman,
                      ViceChairman = c.ViceChairman,
                      Councillors = from cc
                                    in c.CouncilorCommittees
                                    select cc.Councillor
                  }
```

Similarly, to get all of the councillors and the committes that they belong to, you could do something like this:

```
var councillors = from c
                  in Councillors
                  select new
                  {
                      CouncillorName = c.Name,
                      Committes = from cc
                                    in c.CouncilorCommittees
                                    select cc.Committee
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks Mun, your approach is very similar to the one outlined in the article Jason linked to. So basically stick in a junction / link table as per normal database development and treat it as it's own entity. I can work with that, stops me second guessing how I'd put it all together.

Comment: @Mike No probs. That's the approach - add junction table and treat it as it's own entity. I've used this method on a few projects and it works pretty well.